# software to view logs on remote server

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, deployment

I have configured syslog server on my linux machine like this

Linux Machine (syslog client)  -- > Linux Machine (syslog server)

I have configured it and its working properly. Now, the problem is I want to look at the logs located on remote server in a particular directory for example `/var/log/host-ip/httpd.log`.

One way is that I use ssh for that and then see those logs using commands like `tail` etc.

So is there any Browser based graphical utility which I can use on my machine in which I just give the remote folder location, ip-address etc. and the software shows me the logs present on that remote server.

Thanks.